# Flash media don't showing on preview mode in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, flash

First of all sorry for my English. I've a wordpress site. When I click post preview button, I can't see any flash media (Adsense, flash player etc.).

What is the reason for this? (P.S: There is adsense code in my single.php)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress editor usually strips this kind of tags, you would have to insert the following code to your functions.php file to enable it:

```
function change_mce_options($initArray) {
    $ext = 'object[id|type|data|classid|width|height],param[type|data|width|height]';

    if ( isset( $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $ext;
    } else {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $ext;
    }

    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'change_mce_options');
```

Comment: @emlcvdv, could you paste here the part of the code you are having problems with?

Comment: Actually I had trouble with Google Pagespeed module. I removed 'pagespeed EnableFilters combine_javascript;' line from configuration code. And problem solved. Your code is did not influence but It inspired me :) Thank you again.